# Finding the correct "network interface" number for IPv6

Tags: networking, boost-asio, ipv6

I am trying to use Boost for some IPv6 and multicast network communication. I need to construct an IPv6 multicast socket that uses a specific network interface index.

I was able to find the correct multicast option to set the network interface index in boost/asio/ip/detail/socket_option.hpp:
    explicit multicast_request(const boost::asio::ip::address_v6& multicast_address, unsigned long network_interface = 0)

The problem is, I don't know how to find the correct value for the "network_interface" parameter. Is there a way to get the network_interface value using a local IPv6 address that I can provide? I looked in the documentation and examples, but couldn't find anything.

-- Dylan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a platform-independent way to figure this out, just as there is [no portable solution to enumerating the local addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674314/get-local-ip-address-using-boost-asio).

On Linux, you can find what you want in the second column of `/proc/net/if_inet6`, which is also available more robustly through the `rtnetlink(7)` interface.

Answer (score 6):

Each platform provides APIs to enumerate the network interfaces, e.g. [`getifaddrs`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html) for many Unixes and [`GetAdaptersAddresses`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa923123.aspx) for Windows.  Note on Windows there is a separate numerical space for IPv4 and IPv6 adapters which makes the API call [`if_nametoindex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb408409%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) quite confusing.

You may wish to inspect the methods I employed in OpenPGM for portability, considering Windows doesn't really have useful adapter names:

http://code.google.com/p/openpgm/source/browse/trunk/openpgm/pgm/getifaddrs.c

http://code.google.com/p/openpgm/source/browse/trunk/openpgm/pgm/nametoindex.c

http://code.google.com/p/openpgm/source/browse/trunk/openpgm/pgm/indextoaddr.c

http://code.google.com/p/openpgm/source/browse/trunk/openpgm/pgm/indextoname.c

Comment: I have used the `if_nametoindex(3)` function on linux, and it works perfect. I.e.: `int interfaceIndex = if_nametoindex("eth0");   socket.set_option(boost::asio::ip::multicast::join_group(address.to_v6(), interfaceIndex));`