# Boost Asio always returns 0.0.0.0 IP

Tags: c++, networking, boost, boost-asio, ip-address

I have this code in my server (scattered around the constructors etc. but I've left out the unnecessary parts):

```
using namespace boost::asio;
io_service ioserv;
ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(ip::tcp::v4(), 1922);
ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(ioserv, endpoint);
ip::tcp::socket socket(ioserv);
acceptor.accept(socket);
```

Now I want to write my IP to the console. Unfortunately both

```
cout << endpoint.address() << endl;
```

and

```
cout << acceptor.local_endpoint().address() << endl;
```

print

```
0.0.0.0
```

How to get the IP address of my machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where did you get that code?

Try this:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;    

boost::asio::io_service io_service;
tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
tcp::resolver::query query(boost::asio::ip::host_name(), "");
tcp::resolver::iterator iter = resolver.resolve(query);
tcp::resolver::iterator end; // End marker.
while (iter != end)
{
    tcp::endpoint ep = *iter++;
    std::cout << ep << std::endl;
}
```

And take a look at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674314/get-local-ip-address-using-boost-asio).

Comment: Answering your question: As I said, I've left out the unnecessary parts. The acceptor is there because the server accepts connections. For simplicity, I've only included one such accept. Is there anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3):

The default bind-address is INADDR_ANY, which is 0.0.0.0, which means that the socket will accept connections via any interface. Your code is perfectly correct, except that it isn't a correct way to ascertain your IP address. You can get that directly via the Sockets API without creating a socket at all.